# GHC stack overflow hook doesn't' work in Linux dynamic library

Tags: haskell, shared-libraries, ghc

I'm writing a dynamically linked library that includes both C and Haskell code. I'm using the GHC. It's working fine except that when there is a stack overflow in Haskell, the program crashes. It looks like I should be able to catch these errors by adding a hook when I set up the RTS. (https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.10.5/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#hooks-to-change-rts-behaviour)

However, the hook isn't run. The documentation says that it won't work if the library is dynamically linked in Windows, but I'm running in Linux. Am I missing something or is the documentation incomplete?

The hook runs in a stand-alone executable.

---

A little more detail: I'm writing a plug-in for PostgreSQL to allow a user to run haskell code. I'm using [Hint](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint) as the interpreter. Since the user can input possibly bad code, a stack overflow is an issue that must be handled gracefully.

Comment: Uh... XY problem? Why are you encountering stack overflows in the first place? Not something you ever want to need recovering from IMO.

Comment: It looks like you are running untrusted Haskell code. Keep in mind that if the Haskell code is malicious, anything could happen. Watch out for security issues.